# Optimizing TensorFlow code for Efficient Parallel Execution on Multiple CPUs

Tags: python, tensorflow, parallel-processing

I have a TensorFlow code snippet in that I'm attempting to parallelize on multiple CPUs. The original non-parallelized code runs in approximately 11.29 seconds.

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=""
import tensorflow as tf
import time

def matrix_multiplication():
    matrix_size = 4000
    matrix_a = tf.random.normal(shape=(matrix_size, matrix_size))
    matrix_b = tf.random.normal(shape=(matrix_size, matrix_size))

    for i in range(0,2000):
        print(i)
        result = tf.matmul(matrix_a, matrix_b)

    return result

start_time = time.perf_counter()
result_matrix = matrix_multiplication()
```

However, when attempting to use the joblib package for parallel execution (2 CPUs), the runtime increases significantly to 49.50 seconds.

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=""


import tensorflow as tf
import time
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def matrix_multiplication(i):
    matrix_size = 4000
    matrix_a = tf.random.normal(shape=(matrix_size, matrix_size))
    matrix_b = tf.random.normal(shape=(matrix_size, matrix_size))

    for i in range(0,2000):
        print(i)
        result = tf.matmul(matrix_a, matrix_b)+i

    return result


result = Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(matrix_multiplication)(i) for i in range(1,3))
```

I'm seeking advice on optimizing the parallel version to achieve a runtime comparable to the non-parallelized version. How can I modify the parallelized code to ensure that the computation is performed in parallel without a significant increase in runtime? Any insights or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Elizabeth, In your provided code, there are a couple of improvements that can be made to optimize the parallel execution. Your are creating matrix_a and matrix_b inside the matrix_multiplication function, which means they are recreated for every iteration of the loop. This is unnecessary and adds overhead. And also set TensorFlow to use the CPUs explicitly, so it doesn’t try to use GPU resources.